# Can I still boot into Single User Mode if I disable the shell for root?

Tags: single-user

[It's been suggested that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408246/9297), since the `root` account now appears in the accounts database on macOS 10.13.1+ by "default" ([by accident it seems](https://www.macworld.com/article/3238868/macs/macos-high-sierra-root-security-issue-allows-admin-access-to-your-macbut-theres-a-fix.html)), it might be a good security measure to [disable shell access for that account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408245/9297).

Will doing so disable the ability to boot into Single User Mode?

Comment: Single user mode uses /private/etc/passwd for login authentication, not Open Directory.

Comment: @fd0: So setting [`sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/root UserShell /usr/bin/false`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408245/9297) will leave Single User Mode untouched?

Comment: Please don't cross-post

Comment: @patrix: This is a distinct question. Not a cross post. And wasn't there a comment here that focused the question ([and would have avoided the unhelpful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307666/4395))

Comment: I've undeleted the comment but if you think it's important in the long run please add it to the question itself. Also I'm happy to improve the answer if you can add some details on why you consider it unhelpful.

Comment: @patrix: Thanks! Maybe I don't know enough of the details: I'm just tying to determine whether that linked change (disabling the shell in that way) will in fact, kill Single User mode. I'm getting conflicting info on the consequences of doing that, and it all seems to build down to whether that's the case.

Comment: As @fd0 and my answer say: **No**, setting the shell to `/usr/bin/false` with `dscl` has no impact on single user mode. The answers you got to the unix.stackexchange.com version of the question may be valid for Unix/Linux in general, but not for macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @fd0 already commented, "single user mode uses /private/etc/passwd for login authentication, not Open Directory":

```
pse@Mithos:~$ grep ^root: /etc/passwd 
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

but

```
pse@Mithos:~$ sudo dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
```

So single user mode will happily read the content of `/etc/passwd` and start a `root` shell with `/bin/sh` even if you set the shell to false with `dscl`.